# Congruent triangles supplementary

Tags: geometry

Question -

if two triangles have two sides of one equal to two sides of other and included angles are supplementary prove that they have equal area....

My attempt

one angle should be  greater then 90 and other is less then 90..but how to proceed further..i know it is easy question but i cant solve it...

Comment: Are you talking about the angle between the two sides?

Comment: Yes! I will update my question

Comment: Hint: suppose the sides are $AB,BC$. What is the length of the altitude from $A$ to $BC$?

Comment: Still can't get it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the relevant sides be $a,b$ and let the angles be $ C$ and $180^o-C$.

Then the area of the first triangle is $\frac{1}{2}ab\sin C$. Since $\sin C=\sin(180^o-C)$ the second triangle has the same area.

ALTERNATIVE

Join the two triangles along one of the equal edges, say of length $b$. We then have a triangle with base $2a$ such that the original two triangles are on either side of a median.

[Triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW5O9.png)

The two triangles can now be seen to have the same area by a variety of arguments. Perhaps the simplest method is to note that the two triangles have the same height and their bases are equal.

Comment: Are you  happy with the alternative, based upon the fact that a median splits an area in half?

Comment: I've added a diagram and explanation which should help.

Comment: They add to $180^o$ and so the two bases form a straight line in the diagram

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer, i came across this question sometime ago, really appreciate this!